# Where are the assets files related to the application layout in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline

I know that for every controller, there's a separate SASS and CoffeeScript file to keep things organized. But what about styling the application layout itself? How is it that there's no files to put all the styling and JS related to the whole layout?

I know there's application.css and application.js, but I Know these are not to be messed with because these files put everything together.

I hope someone could put me in the right track!

Comment: You can just create your own master.css.scss file to put all your styles in. They just create new .css and .js files to keep things organized. Using them is optional. However, when I create new coffeescript files I usually use the ones for the specified controller so I can easily find the code down the road if it needs updates. But since rails compile's assets, all your css files and js files get compiled into one file each for production.

Comment: yeah that's what i'm doing right now. I have application.sass for example. But I figured rails developers must have a reason not to add it as a default!

Answer (score 0):

the application.css and application.js are manifest file and there you can see require_tree . that load all your js file for application.js and in same manner for application.css now on compiling assets pipeline make a minified version of that and create only one file that hold all the js in itself if you want to create two manifest file you can also do that .